# I am trying to us a custom validator to check if a textbox is empty and then display a message to the user that the field must be filled

Tags: c#

Here is what I have. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
protected void CustomValidator4_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    string n;
    e.IsValid = string.Empty(e.Value, out n);
}
```

Comment: Your line of code makes no sense whatsoever.  You need to learn C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) instead.

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1"  runat="server"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                    Display="Static"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter something here"
                    runat="server"/>
```

Note that the `CustomValidator` will not even fire when the user has not entered anything. Therefore you have to set [`ValidateEmptyText="True"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx).